# No me deja tener mas de 2 routes al mismo tiempo

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-8, router

Tengo varias rutas en mi aplicacion pero por alguna razón solo me coge las 2 primeras (teniendo 4), cuando cambio el orden de las rutas en el codigo me sigue cogiendo las 2 primeras, he borrado el cache de las rutas pero sigue sin cogerme todas, que puede estar pasando?

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
});

return Route::post(
    '/home/insert',
    [AuroracoinController::class, 'store']
);

return Route::post(
    '/home/deleteAll',
    [AuroracoinController::class, 'deleteAll']
);

return Route::get(
    '/home/auroracoin',
    [AuroracoinController::class, 'index']
);
```

Solo me coge la de /home y la de /home/insert, pero si por ejemplo pongo la de /home/deleteAll encima de la de /home/insert me coge esa en su lugar.

Este es el output de route:list

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estaba utilizando múltiples instrucciones de `return` al mismo tiempo en cada llamada al controlador, la solución fue eliminar el prefijo de `return` antes de cada Route